# Is POI category valid for android auto submision to Google play?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, manifest, android-auto

I have submited a new version of my app, that includes Android auto version, and It was rejected.
[image]

```
<application>
...

.
// android auto

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
                android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc"/>
        <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.car.app.minCarApiLevel"
                android:value="1"/>

        <service
                android:name=".programameudisservice"
                android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.car.app.CarAppService" />
                <category android:name="androidx.car.app.category.POI"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </service>
        // android auto
..
</application>
```

I'm using POI category in my android manifest, as is mentioned in docs:
https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps#supported-app-categories
https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps

Anyone knows if is it really suppported by Google play?

I open a appeal, but not answer yet (I think I will not have this answer never)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally was acceptet using PARKING category

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).